# Following code crashes in x64 bit but not x86 build

Tags: c++, encryption

I've always been using a xor encryption class for my 32 bit applications but recently I have started working on a 64 bit one and encountered the following crash: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCBlJ.png

Here's the xor class I'm using:

```
// xor.h
#pragma once

template <int XORSTART, int BUFLEN, int XREFKILLER>
class XorStr
{
private:
    XorStr();
public:
    char s[BUFLEN];

    XorStr(const char* xs);
    ~XorStr()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFLEN; i++) s[i] = 0;
    }
};

template <int XORSTART, int BUFLEN, int XREFKILLER>
XorStr<XORSTART, BUFLEN, XREFKILLER>::XorStr(const char* xs)
{
    int xvalue = XORSTART;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < (BUFLEN - 1); i++)
    {
        s[i] = xs[i - XREFKILLER] ^ xvalue;
        xvalue += 1;
        xvalue %= 256;
    }
    s[BUFLEN - 1] = (2 * 2 - 3) - 1;
}
```

The crash occurs when I try to use the obfuscated string but doesnt necessarily happen 100% of the times (never happens on 32 bit, however). Here's a small example of a 64 bit app that will crash on the second obfuscated string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xor.h"

int main()
{
    // no crash
    printf(/*123456789*/XorStr<0xDE, 10, 0x017A5298>("\xEF\xED\xD3\xD5\xD7\xD5\xD3\xDD\xDF" + 0x017A5298).s);

    // crash
    printf(/*123456*/XorStr<0xE3, 7, 0x87E64A05>("\xD2\xD6\xD6\xD2\xD2\xDE" + 0x87E64A05).s);

    return 0;
}
```

The same app will run perfectly fine if built in 32 bit.

Here's the HTML script to generate the obfuscated strings: https://pastebin.com/QsZxRYSH

I need to tweak this class to work on 64 bit because I have a lot of strings that I already have encrypted that I need to import from a 32 bit project into the one I'm working on at the moment, which is 64 bit. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post the error message as plain-text into the question and mention which line the debugger is pointing to as its origin. Also please show how you are using this class, best case as [mcve]. One immediate issue would be `XREFKILLER` being anything but `0`, in which case the pointer passed to the constructor would need to be properly advanced that `-XREFKILLER` is still inside the character array's bounds. The other template parameters also need appropiate values (e.g. `BUFLEN>=1`) and the character array must have at least matching length. The destructor serves no purpose at all.

Comment: There are several ways this code snippet could be made to crash. Please add a [mcve] so that we can better determine which one you're encountering.

Comment: Also I hope `because I have a lot of strings that I already have encrypted for database connection ` does not mean that you use this in any setting requiring any level of secrecy on data transmitted, because this cipher can be broken basically instantly, even without looking up the hard-coded key (`XORSTART`) in the binary.

Comment: Your `XorStr` destructor can be seen to do nothing and most modern compilers will optimize it out with reasonable optimization levels. That is *not* a reasonable way to destroy sensitive data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access violation is because `0x87E64A05` is larger than the largest value a signed 32bit integer can hold (which is `0x7FFFFFFF`).

Because `int` is likely 32bit, then `XREFKILLER` cannot hold `0x87E64A05` and so its value will be implementation-defined.

This value is then used later to subtract again from `xs` after the pointer passed was artificially advanced by the *literal* `0x87E64A05` which would be interpreted as `long` or `long long` to make the value fit, depending on whether `long` is 32bit or larger and therefore wouldn't narrowing into the implementation defined value.

Therefore you are effectively left with some random pointer in `xs[i - XREFKILLER]` and this is likely to give undefined behavior, e.g. an access violation.

If compiled for 32bit x86 it probably so happens that `int` and pointers have the same bit-size and that the implementation-defined over-/underflow and narrowing behaviors happen to be such that the addition and subtraction cancel correctly as expected. If however the pointer type is larger than 32bit this cannot function.

---

There is no point to `XREFKILLER` at all. It just does one calculation that is immediately reverted (if there is no over-/underflow).

---

Note that the fact that the compiler accepts the narrowing in the template argument at all is a bug. Your program is ill-formed and the compiler should give you an error message.
In GCC for example this bug persists until version 8.2, but has been fixed on current trunk (i.e. version 9).

---

You will have similar problems with `XORSTART` if `char` happens to be `signed` on your platform, because then your provided values wont fit into it. But in that case you will have to enable warnings, because that won't be a conversion making the program ill-formed. Also the behavior of `^` may not be as you expect if `char` is `signed` on your system.

---

It is not clear what the point of

```
s[BUFLEN - 1] = (2 * 2 - 3) - 1;
```

is. It should be:

```
s[BUFLEN - 1] = '\0';
```

---

Passing the resulting string to `printf` as first argument will lead to spurious undefined behavior if the result string happens to contain a `%` which would be interpreted as introduction to a format specifier. Use `std::cout`.

---

If you want to use `printf` you need to write `std::printf` and `#include<cstdio>` to guarantee that it will be available. However, since this is C++, you should be using `std::cout` instead anyway.

---

More fundamentally your output string may happen to contain a `0` other than the terminating one after your transformation. This would be interpreted as end of the C-style string. This seems like a major design flaw and you probably want to use `std::string` instead for that reason (and because it is better style).